# Azure container service not creating the agent nodes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-cli, azure-container-service, windows-container

I have been working on the deployment of windows container from Azure Container Registry to Azure Container Service with Kubernetes Orchestra it was working fine previously. 
Now I'm trying to create an acs kubernetes cluster of windows but the create command is only creating a master node and while deploying I'm getting the following error **No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: MatchNodeSelector (1)**

I have followed this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-windows-walkthrough to create the windows based kubernetes cluster.

This is the command I have used to create the cluster

```
az acs create --orchestrator-type=kubernetes \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name=myK8sCluster \
    --agent-count=2 \
    --generate-ssh-keys \
    --windows --admin-username azureuser \
    --admin-password myPassword12
```

As per the above documentation, the above command should create a cluster named myK8sCluster with one Linux master node and two Windows agent nodes.

To verify the creation of cluster I have used the below command

```
kubectl get nodes

NAME                    STATUS  AGE       VERSION
k8s-master-98dc3136-0   Ready   5m        v1.7.7
```

According to the above command, it shows that it created only the Linux master node, not the two windows agent nodes.

But in my case I require the windows agent nodes to deploy a windows based container in the cluster.

So I assume that due this I'm getting the following error while deploying  **No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: MatchNodeSelector (1)**

Comment: AKS is supporting windows containers now in preview form. Try AKS instead

Comment: Yes, I know but the above was working fine for me before

Comment: My understanding ACS is depreciated so not sure why would you want to spend cycles troubleshooting dead technology

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation points out, ACS with a target of Kubernetes is deprecated. You want to use AKS (Azure Kubernetes as a Service).

To go about this, start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli

Make sure you have the [latest version of the CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) installed on your machine if you choose to do it locally, or use the [Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview).

Follow the guide on the rest of the steps as it will walk you through the commands.

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, as I know the possible reason is that you need to enable the WindowsPreview feather. You can have a check through the CLI command like this:

```
az feature list -o table --query "[?contains(name, 'Microsoft.ContainerService/WindowsPreview')].{Name:name,State:properties.state}"
```

When it's OK, you also need to pay attention to the Kubernetes version. When I use the command that you have used, then the windows nodes are created successfully, but it just shows the master when I execute the command `kubectl get nodes`. Even if I can see the windows node in the group.

Then I try the command with additional parameter `--orchestrator-version` and set the value as 1.12.7 and the whole command like below:

```
az acs create --orchestrator-type=kubernetes \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name=myK8sCluster \
    --agent-count=2 \
    --generate-ssh-keys \
    --windows --admin-username azureuser \
    --admin-password myPassword12 \
    --orchestrator-version \
    --location westcentralus
```

Then it works well and the command `kubectl get nodes -o wide` show like below:

[image]

But as you know, the ACS will be deprecated. So I would suggest you use the [AKS with Windows node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli) in the preview version. Or you can use the [aks-engine](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine) as the AKS Engine is the next version of the ACS-Engine project.

Comment: When I checked the windows preview feather it says it is not registered - Microsoft.ContainerService/WindowsPreview  NotRegistered
Can you say how to enable it

Comment: @Hub Yeah, just like the action in the AKS with windows node. Two CLI commands: `az extension add --name aks-preview` and `az feature register --name WindowsPreview --namespace Microsoft.ContainerService`.

Comment: I think this is for AKS windows preview, in my case I'm using ACS windows should this will solve the issue

Comment: okay sure, but the acs create shows the below errro The template deployment 'azurecli1558682305.465570415868' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is 'e6ca13c4-370f-48c5-a9bb-5aed015cd3f8'. See inner errors for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.

Comment: az acs create --orchestrator-type=kubernetes \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name=myK8sCluster \
    --agent-count=2 \
    --generate-ssh-keys \
    --windows --admin-username azureuser \
    --admin-password myPassword12 \
    --orchestrator-version \
    --location westcentralus

Comment: @Hub Please set the version value just like 1.12.7. Do not leave it empty.

Comment: az acs create --orchestrator-type=kubernetes --resource-group EwQIMSCloud --name=ewqimscluster --agent-count=2 --generate-ssh-keys --windows --admin-username hubino --admin-password Omnex123 --orchestrator-version=1.12.7 this is the command I have used but it also generates only the master node

Comment: Still, I'm getting the following error while deploying No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: MatchNodeSelector

Comment: @Hub Do you enable the WindowsPreview feather?

Comment: @Hub Maybe you can just check if WindowsPreview feather is enabled, then copy the CLI command in my answer and just change some parameters values. The `--orchestrator-version` just available in some [locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acs?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acs-create).

Comment: I have already enabled the windows preview, will check with different location

Comment: @Hub The ACS works well in my side, which location do you use? Maybe I can take a test for you.

Comment: I'm using centralus

Comment: @Hub I also just get the master in centralus location even the node already create successfully. You can try the westcentralus location.

Comment: I tried all the solution you provided but it is not working, I have already raised a support ticket in Azure thanks a lot for your help throughout